# how to map key of a dictionary to a variable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary

I'm creating a unit test to see if a dictionary has a certain key inside. here is the part of the program which involves adding key/value pairs to the dictionary:

```
    public void Subscribe(EvtId inEvent, EvtDelegate inCallbackMethod)
    {
        if(mEventMap.ContainsKey(inEvent))
        {
            mEventMap[inEvent] += inCallbackMethod;
        }
        else
        {
            mEventMap.Add(inEvent, inCallbackMethod);
        }
    }
```

And here is the piece of unit test code:

```
    public void SubscribeTest()
    {
        EventHandlerCs target = new EventHandlerCs(eLayer.1stLayer);

        target.Subscribe(EvtId.AccessChange, AccessChangeVT);

        EventHandlerCs_Accessor target2 = new EventHandlerCs_Accessor(eLayer.1stLayer);

        EvtId expectedEvt = EvtId.AccessChange;
        EvtId actualEvt;

        if (target2.mEventMap.ContainsKey(EvtId.AccessChange))
        {
            // ???
            // Assert.AreEqual(expectedEvt, actualEvt);
        }
    }
```

how do I map the actual value of the key/ the key itself (once I've found it in the Dictionary using the `ContainsKey` method) to the `actualEvt` variable in the unit test code?

Feel free to ask for more info about the question if you need to do so.

**Update:** the dictionary in question is set to `private`, so that's why I had to use the Accessor.

Answer (score 2):

isn't it just `target2.mEventMap[EvtId.AccessChange]` ?

Comment: That's what I thought, but it can't be this easy. There has to be something else going on that isn't made clear in the question.

Comment: I know, but I thought I should ask anyway :)

Comment: I've tried it, but what it does is get the value associated with the key.

@siride, what do you have in mind? I'm more than willing to clear things up about the question.

Comment: But isn't the value of the key always going to be `EvtId.AccessChange`?

Comment: @GlennSlaven - i'm sorry, you lost me there >_< LOL once it's in the Dictionary, yeah it's always going to be `EvtId.AccessChange` .

Comment: @Anthony: if you want the key, you already have the key (because that's how you would get the value or check to see if it's in the dictionary). That's what Glenn Slaven is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the TryGetValue function on the dictionary.  A good explanation of that can be found here.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/trygetvalue

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    d.Add("key", 0);
    // This code does two hash lookups.
    int value;
    if (d.TryGetValue("key", out value))
    {
        d["key"] = value + 1;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking with **Contains** call the **TryGetValue** to check if the key exists and also to retrieve the value if it does.

```
 if (target2.mEventMap.TryGetValue(EvtId.AccessChange, out actualEvt))
{
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedEvt, actualEvt);
}
```

Comment: `TryGetValue` gets the value associated with the key. I'm not interested in whatever values the key has, I'm interested in just the key itself.

Comment: You already have the key, it is based on the key that you are searching even in the ContainsKey. The key you already have is the same key in the dictionary.